# NameError: name 'django_filters' is not defined

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, postgresql, django-filter

I am trying to use the Django package: [Django Filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter)
I installed it via Pip, made sure I was running supported versions of Python(3.6), and Django(2.0), but whenever I try to run my application, I get the following error:

```
class Table1(models.Model, django_filters.FilterSet):
NameError: name 'django_filters' is not defined
```

Here's a sample of my code, with the names changed to protect my work.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField, SearchQuery
from django_filters import FilterSet



class Table1(models.Model, django_filters.FilterSet):
    field1 = models.IntegerField(db_column='field1', blank=True, null=True)  
    field2 = models.NullBooleanField(db_column='field2')  
    field3= models.IntegerField(db_column='field3', blank=True, null=True)  
    field4= models.TextField(db_column='field4', blank=True, null=False, primary_key=True)  

    #def __str__(self):
     #   return self.sid

    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'Table1'
       unique_together = (('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4'),)
```

filters.py:

```
from .models import Table1
import django_filters

class Table1Filter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Table1
        fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from django_tables2.export.export import TableExport
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchRank
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic import *

from .models import *
from .tables import *
from .forms  import *
from .filters import Table1Filter

def table1(request):
    filter = Table1Filter(request.GET, queryset=Table1.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'table1.html', {'filter': filter})
```

I wrote some basic filtering stuff manually and then realized that Django Filter(s) was a thing and figured I shouldn't reinvent the wheel. The goal with this is to display data from an exisiting database and allow the end user to filter it. If there's a better way to do this, I am all ears. Thanks for your input, and taking the time to read this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably in circular imports...

in models.py you import `from django_filters import FilterSet` then you import in `fitlers.py` one of models from `models.py` and the same time `django_filters`.

This may causing problems. I guess you don't need importing that library and FilterSet in your models.py

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps because you haven't imported `django_filters` in your models.py file.

```
import django_filters # instead of django_filters import FilterSet
```

or use it the other way around.

Comment: I tried this, and got a different error, not sure how just importing the whole package would fix this problem...                                          
                                                                                                         
New error: TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Comment: @J.Sax In your models.py file, you're importing `FilterSet` and not the module `django_filters`. It's fine but then in the next line, you have something like `class Msysaces1(models.Model, django_filters.FilterSet):`, now obviously it is an error since django_filters are not imported. You either need to import django_filters or change the line.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it's not right. I am doing a similar import for 'models' and use it in the class, without error. Again, I've tried what you suggested, and get a different error all together, which is included in my previous comment.

Comment: @J.Sax That's a whole new different problem which has to with `models.Model` and `django_filters.FilterSet` having different metaclass, but it doesn't mean your import is not incorrect. You probably need to read about Python imports to understand them. By the way, I don't think it's a good idea to inherit models from `FilterSet`.